# Possible to favorite questions to a particular section?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I want to mark a question as favorite so I can save it and see it later, but I'm wondering if I can organize my favorite questions and keep them under different headings.

For example, I want a "django" favorites section, and a "vim" favorites section. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Are the questions already tagged with [django] or [vim]? If yes, you can just search for them: [`infavorites:mine [vim]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+%5Bvim%5D).